# Load test a server port with login details

Tags: apache, load-testing, apachebench

I am trying to load test a specific port of a server. I need to login to the port with some content. I have been looking at Apache Bench as it but havent found a way of doing this. Any help or advice on other similar tools would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) - it is way more advanced multiprotocol load testing tool which even has record-and-replay capability via built-in [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

JMeter is GUI-based so no programming languages knowledge is required.

See [Logging in to a web-site](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#logging_in) user manual chapter to get the overall idea.

If you find JMeter a viable alternative to Apache Bench I would recommend attending free [JMeter Academy](https://www.blazemeter.com/jmeter-tutorial) - probably the fastest and the most efficient way of ramping up on JMeter.

Comment: Thank You. I have looked briefly into JMeter, it seems to be the most popular.